# Does iterative calls across instances consitute recursion?

Tags: recursion

My question is about whether or not iterating through a list of nodes satisfies the 'function calls itself' definition of recursion.  I am of the opinion that 'calling itself' literally means the function calls out to itself, while others are saying, 'itself' could be the identical function of a second (or third) node.

Not that I know JavaScript, but hopefully this will get the idea across:

```
Class Node { 
  var value = 0;
  var kids = [];

  var list = function(){
     var rtn = value + "\n";
     if (kids.length > 0){
        for (var i=0; i<kids.length; i++){
           rtn += kids[i].list();
        }
     }
     return rtn;
   };
}
```

Now supposing I populate the kids array with node objects, and then call the list() function of the head node, it will append the value of the head node, and then append the values of all the kids' nodes.  My question is, is the line `rtn += kids[i].list();` actually a recursive call?

As I indicated, I would say not because the (identical) functions are running in different nodes, but others are saying yes - its the exact same code.  I can find no definitive answers using Google, so might I ask what the consensus is here?

Answer (score 1):

It is most certainly recursion. Suppose you had written the function in such a way that it took a node as an argument, instead of being a method of the node. In that case it would be calling itself with different arguments. If you look at it right, the node to which it is attached is just a different set of arguments (albeit unwritten ones) to the same function. The function is still calling itself.

Also, recursion is not limited strictly to a function directly calling itself. You could write a function `a()` which calls another function `b()`, which in turn calls `a()` again. `a()` has still called itself, just with the help of `b()`.